# Ms SQL function to make IP addresses lexicographically comparable

Tags: sql-server, ip, lexicographic-ordering

I found following code to stuff IP adresses with zeros to make it lexicographically comparable.
The code works finde but I need it as a scalar function in SQL. 
Can you transform that in Code to create a scalar function that does the same?
We use SQL Server 2008 R2 at the moment.

```
DECLARE @a as NVARCHAR(15)
SET @a = '2.18.4.14'

SELECT 
    @a = CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@a) < 4 
            THEN STUFF(@a,1,0,REPLICATE('0',4-CHARINDEX('.',@a,1))) 
        ELSE @a 
    END
, 
    @a = CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@a) < 8 
            THEN STUFF(@a,5,0,REPLICATE('0',8-CHARINDEX('.',@a, 5))) 
        ELSE @a 
    END
, 
    @a = CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.',@a) < 12 
            THEN STUFF(@a,9,0,REPLICATE('0',12-CHARINDEX('.',@a, 9))) 
        ELSE @a 
    END
, 
    @a = CASE 
        WHEN LEN(@a) < 15 
            THEN STUFF(@a,13,0,REPLICATE('0',15-LEN(@a))) 
        ELSE @a 
    END

SELECT @a
```

Can you explain how that code works? 
I understand what CHARINDEX, STUFF and REPLICATE do but I dont understand the steps how the IP adresse @a is modified by the CASE steps. 
Is ist a scalar value or a table?

Comment: Why a Scalar Function? Assuming this is going to be run against a table/dataset a Table-Value function would be far faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use a Table-Value Function, not a Scalar function. Table-Value Function far out perform Scalar functions, and if you're going to be doing to against a dataset, then you'll notice a large speed increase.

Firstly, this makes use of Jeff Moden's [DelmitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). If, however, you're using SQL Server 2016 then you can use `STRING_SPLIT` (I don't what version your using). Then the function is as simple as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Lexicon_IP_fn (@IPAddress VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),STUFF((SELECT '.' + RIGHT('000' + DS.Item,3)
                                      FROM DelimitedSplit8K(@IPAddress, '.') DS
                                      FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) AS Lexicon_IP
);
```

You can call the function using `CROSS APPLY`. For example:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('1.1.1.1'),('123.123.1.42'),('127.0.0.1')) V([IP]))
SELECT [IP], LIP.Lexicon_IP
FROM VTE
     CROSS APPLY Lexicon_IP_fn([IP]) LIP;
```

Which returns:

```
IP           Lexicon_IP
------------ ---------------
1.1.1.1      001.001.001.001
123.123.1.42 123.123.001.042
127.0.0.1    127.000.000.001
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. We use SQL Server 2008 R2 at the moment.

Comment: @Ephedra TVF's are available in 2008 R2. They were introduced with SQL Server 2008, if I recall correctly. So the above will work.

Comment: I also cant use STRING_SPLIT because the compatibility level of the database is 100 and I can not set it higher.  :(

Comment: The SQL Server does not know DelimitedSplit8K
Invalid object name 'DelimitedSplit8K'.

Comment: I got It :) 

With help of google I found a split function that works and used that instead of 'DelimitedSplit8K'. Now it works.  Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my post, *this makes use of Jeff Moden's [DelmitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)*. That blue text is a hyperlink to an article which contains the function. I then also advise that `STRING_SPLIT` is only available in 2016 onwards. :)

Comment: OHHH... now I understand. I copied the code for creating DelimitedSplit8k. I first thougt it was an integrated function because I first only saw the performance discussion...
Many thanks and sorry I m a little bit slowly and chaotic :D